# Ubuntu 16.04 stuck after log in

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, dell

After putting password for log in, the boot process stops. I can see only the desktop image without any application, yet I can move the cursor. I can do nothing except open a terminal by `ctrl+alt+f1`.
I got the problem since two days so I've tried a lot of stuff already to get this work around. I try to summarize the steps taken thus far:
I started with the easier things, like this:

```
$ sudo su
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
$ apt-get install unity
$ reboot
```

But nothing worked.
I've then booted in recovery mode to look deeper for problems. `Running      dpkg Repair broken packages` in recovery mode asks me for upgrading the system. Giving it yes, I got an error in fetching datas, like I don't have network connection. I then moved to networking from the menu below:

[Ubuntu recovery mode menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a17tf.png)

And I realized there was a problem with `resolv.conf`. More precisely:

> /etc/resolv.conf no such file or directory

At this point I thought to let boot-repair do the work.
I booted from a USB, selected Try Ubuntu, and did this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

I followed the instructions and everything's seemed to be fine.
But still, I'm not able to boot.
I'm not an Ubuntu expert, I just tried to figure it on myself looking at suggestions found on the web. Maybe the whole thing is easier but I can't get the point.

Some specifications about my system:

`lsb_release -a` output:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

`sudo lshw` output:

> ```
> ubuntu                    
> description: Laptop
> product: Latitude E6430 (Latitude E6430)
> vendor: Dell Inc.
> version: 01
> serial: 24HLZW1
> width: 64 bits
> capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 vsyscall32
> configuration: boot=normal chassis=laptop sku=Latitude E6430 uuid=44454C4C-3400-1048-804C-B2C04F5A5731
> ```

`lspci | grep VGA` output:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

Thank you in advance for any attempt to help.

Comment: And if you move the mouse-cursor to upper left corner ? And eventually click there, if nothing happens automatically.

Comment: No, nothing happens. I can't click anywhere basically. If, for istance, I click the right mouse button in the middle of desktop, none window pops up. The only thing I can do is open up the hard terminal.